# how to disable value in a drop down when the document is in one stage

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a drop down box with the values Development, Review and Baseline.

When the Document is in the Development stage, when the user clicks on the drop down the Baseline value should be disabled. How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve the [SPListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.aspx) instance by iterating over the Document Library list. Then, utilize the [Level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.level.aspx) and [ModerationInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.moderationinformation.aspx) properties to determine the document draft/published and approval status.